# HardhatError: HH1: You are not inside a Hardhat project

Tags: hardhat

Adding Hardhat version 2.12.2 to an existing project either manually to the package.json or by executing one of the commands:

- `npm i hardhat`
- `npm i --save-dev hardhat`
- `yarn add hardhat`
- `yarn add --dev hardhat`

Gave the following error:

> HardhatError: HH1: You are not inside a Hardhat project.

Answer (score 2):

The error was resolved by adding a file named `hardhat.config.js` to the project root directory.

This file can also be added by executing `npx hardhat` and then selecting `Create an empty hardhat.config.js`.

I think that the error is misleading and it should be something like this:

> "HardhatError: HH1: Could not find the file `hardhat.config.js`. Are you not inside a Hardhat project?"

Or something like:

> "HardhatError: HH1: You may not be inside a Hardhat project. Ensure running `npx hardhat` at this directory?"

(You can find more on the discussion at: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1400. But it is limited to collaborators now.)